# Best server to sync two machines

Tags: ntp

I have a machine in Sydney and a machine in London, both AWS instances fwiw.

I wish to time sync them.  I'm having trouble deciding whether its best to have one serve the other, or have them both be served by a server (say, the default ubuntu ntp server pool).  Or, since they're both AWS EC2 instances, does this mean in this situation an amazon server is actually the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth you should sync them both separately from reliable sources located close to each of your AWS servers. (e.g a few servers at either end of the world to avoid unnecessary RTT etc.)

NTP likes to have a minimum of 3 and ideally 5 servers to sync from. Provided the servers you pick are from a trusted consistent source you should be fine and shouldn't experience any issues. If you sync both servers separately then you don't have to worry about one of your machines going mad and bringing the other one out of sync in relation to the rest of the world, or doing anything odd.

If you run a large private network then you should consider your own timing source.

A couple of examples;

```
[AU NTP Pool] ---> [AU Server] 
[UK NTP Pool] ---> [UK Server]
```

Each server is independently synced from the closest source from the pool, the servers are independent of each other and should be correct in reference to 'external' time. Servers could be different if there is an underlying issue with one pool for example. Only a full network or configuration outage on 1 server will break sync on that 1 server not both.

```
[AU NTP Pool] ---> [AU Server] <---> [UK Server] <--- [UK NTP Pool]
```

As above but the 2 servers also talk to each other. Would cover against *external* network outages to the pool but allow internal access within AWS between the servers. 1 external failure shouldn't result in a loss of sync to either server.

```
[AU Server] ---> [UK Server] <--- [NTP Pool]
```

With this config if the UK server lost connectivity to the pool it would free run and both servers could end up out of sync to 'external' time.

The easiest thing to avoid administration, give the most consistent coverage is to use the 2nd example where both servers talk to external trusted sources, and to each other. That way you should be covered against most things - but do take the time to select your upstream servers carefully.

Ideally you want to gather some stability stats on them before deciding your production setup - you want a low stratum (1 or 2 if you can find them) and a low RTT between your servers and the intended ntp server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I get less accuracy if I sync one machine to the other due to the high latency?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I'd just like to understand more about choice of servers. "NTP likes to have 3-5 servers." Does this mean 3-5 pools, or a single pool will suffice? The default config (Ubuntu 16.04) is `pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org offline iburst`. I googled for alternative NTP servers and pool.ntp.org suggests "in most cases it's best to use pool.ntp.org to find a server; the system will try finding the closest available servers for you". I'm syncing with a stratum 2 server. Seems legit?

Comment: @JSStuball  So when I talk about having 3-5 servers I'm talking about having a minimum of 3-5 lines in the config file that start with `server ...` (Eg `1.debian.pool.ntp.org` `2.debian.pool.ntp.org` `3.debian.pool.ntp.org`) If you have a working install do `ntpq -pcrv` and post the details in the question and I'll be able to explain some of the stuff you see. Stratum 2 is fine - ideally there in the same country as the server your syncing too.

Comment: Alright great. One final thought - why sync the two machines to *each other* at all since each of them has 3-5 redundancies built into their list of (nearby) servers/pools, and each machine will have far lower RTT to a close by public server than the other aws machine? The probability of 4 or 5 pools going down simultaneously is... beyond remote, right?

Comment: @JSStuball purely to cover against one of the machines having an internet side failure. So if your route from UK out of AWS was broken but the internal AWS links where still working for example. Its pure preference but it's what I'd personally do.

Comment: Ok I'm with you. Yeah I hadn't conceived of a situation where the AWS London box and AWS Sydney box could talk to each other but the rest of the internet was broken. Thanks again.

Comment: @JSStuball It kinda depends on the AWS network. I know with a lot of VPS's you have the option of a private internal network between boxes which keeps to internal routes only. If you want to consolidate some of your comments into your question we can clean these up and I'll do the same later when i'm up.